# How can I align a subheader to the title?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a subheader (highlighted in the screenshot).

My code entirely removes the element from the page. Note that while the element is still in the DOM, it is removed visually and any other conceivable way (you can't tab to it or its children, it is ignored by screen readers, etc).

```css
body {
  background-image: url(./assets/shutterstock_1680256285.jpeg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0, 88, 147, 1);
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  height: 66px;
  background: rgba(0, 88, 147, 1);
  background: -webkit-gradient( left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(86%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)));
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(86%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)), to(rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)));
  background: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1) 59%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1) 86%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1) 100%);
  align-items: baseline;
}

.logo {
  min-height: 66px;
  width: 288px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  padding-left: 16%;
}

.header {
  border-bottom: white solid 1.3px;
}

.banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: calc(350px / 2);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(19, 101, 155);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.banner h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>RGP Maintenance</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://resources.renlearnrp.com/scripts/master-css/master.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://resources.renlearnrp.com/scripts/webfonts/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
      <object class="logo" data="https://resources-zone99.renaissance-go.com/scripts/logos/svg/renaissance-learning-horizontal.svg#white"></object>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <center>
      <h1>Planned Maintenance</h1>
      <p>You've come to the right place, but your site is unavailable for a few hours <br> while we perform scheduled updates that will help you accelerate learning.
      </p>

  </div>
  </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what is the problem?

Comment: I am unable to get the sub heading in that correct spot  I have highlighted in the above screenshot. Hence assistance required @NirBerko

Comment: Could you give us a bit more detail what you want to achieve? Is it the position of the subheader? like you want it to be below the mainheader and it doesnt work?

Comment: @Warden330 Correct! I am trying to match the screenshot above but somehow it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. Also you shouldn't use `center`, we are not in 1990 anymore. "Doesn't work" is no error explanation, please show what you tried and what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. You can do by using `flex` and using `align item: center` css property on your `.logo-wrapper`

Also i have added a `span` with a class of `.sub_header` for your sub header text and giving margin-left of `2em` to move your sub header.

Run snippet below.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(./assets/shutterstock_1680256285.jpeg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0, 88, 147, 1);
}

.header_top {}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  height: 66px;
  background: rgba(0, 88, 147, 1);
  background: -webkit-gradient( left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(86%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)));
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1)), color-stop(86%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)), to(rgba(119, 196, 42, 1)));
  background: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 88, 147, 1) 59%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1) 86%, rgba(119, 196, 42, 1) 100%);
  align-items: baseline;
}

.logo {
  min-height: 66px;
  width: 288px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.sub_header {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  padding-left: 16%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  border-bottom: white solid 1.3px;
}

.banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: calc(350px / 2);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(19, 101, 155);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: fit-content;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.banner h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>RGP Maintenance</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://resources.renlearnrp.com/scripts/master-css/master.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://resources.renlearnrp.com/scripts/webfonts/webfont.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-wrapper">
      <object class="logo" data="https://resources-zone99.renaissance-go.com/scripts/logos/svg/renaissance-learning-horizontal.svg#white"></object>
      <span class="sub_header">Accelerating Learning for all</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <center>
      <h1>Planned Maintenance</h1>
      <p>You've come to the right place, but your site is unavailable for a few hours <br> while we perform scheduled updates that will help you accelerate learning.
      </p>
      <p>Contact help@renaissance.com with questions.</p>
  </div>
  </center>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the logo-wrapper div your subheader text, and use flexbox and `align-items: flex-end;`

```
.logo-wrapper {
    padding-left: 16%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Read more about flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox